# change the DCB structure of a boost::asio::serial_port

Tags: serial-port, boost-asio

I'd like to disable RTSControl using `boost::asio::serial_port::set_option` function.  and also be able to raise or lower the `DTR` line?

```
boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate baud_option(115200);       
serialPort.set_option(baud_option);
```

The standard options work great, but I can't figure out, how to change the
`DCB` structure, or how to control the RS232 signal lines.

Answer (score 0):

[Settable serial port option requirements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SettableSerialPortOption.html) (emphasis mine):

> In the table below, X denotes a serial
>   port option class, a denotes a value
>   of X, ec denotes a value of type
>   error_code, and s denotes a value of
>   implementation-defined type storage
>   (where storage is the **type DCB on
>   Windows** and termios on POSIX
>   platforms), and u denotes an
>   identifier.